# Play, Pause and Delete in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the `value is 1`, I could get the `ON` button displayed and if `value is 0`, I could get the `OFF` button displayed in the cards.

Only If `value = 1`(ON), all the buttons like `play`, `pause` and `delete` should be **Enabled**.

If the `value = 0 (OFF)`, all the buttons like `play`, `pause` and `delete` should be **Disabled**.

The problem is, I could get `OFF` button in first card and `ON` button enabled in the next 2 cards.

Since the `OFF` button is enabled all the buttons (play, pause and delete) were **disabled** in the first card.

The condition is, We can't press the `pause` button directly without pressing the `play` button.

So ,I used

```
$('.pause').prop('disabled', true);
```

If I press the `play` button, `play` button and the `delete` button should be **disabled**. `Pause`button should be **Enabled**.

If I press the `pause` button, `pause` button should be **disabled**.`play button` and `delete` button should be Enabled.

It works fine in card3. But, If I press `play` in card2 , the `pause` button in card2 is **disabled**, but `pause` button  is **enabled** in card3. It doesn't works fine in card2. If the click event is in `card2`, It gets reflected in `card3`. But that should not be the case. If I click the `Controls(play, pause and delete)` it should be `enabled/disabled` in the same card.

Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/DarKV/pen/BaRXvLm

Could someone please help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code snippet:-

```
var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  var target = card[i].id;
  var cardId = document.getElementById(target);
  console.log(cardId);
  var val = $(cardId).attr("value");
  // If value is 0, disable the play, pause and delete controls
  if (val== 0) 
{
     $(cardId).find(".off").show();
     $(cardId).find(".on").hide();
     // If Val is  0 disable all the controls 'Play, 'Pause' and 'Delete'.
     $(cardId).find('.controls button').prop('disabled', true);
} 
 else
{
    $(cardId).find(".off").hide();
    $(cardId).find(".on").show();
    // If val is 1, enable all the controls.
    $(cardId).find(".pause").prop('disabled', true);
   
    // On clicking play button, display and delete
    $(cardId).find(".play").on("click", function () {
         $(this).prop("disabled", true);
         $(this).parent(cardId).find(".delete").prop("disabled", true);
         $(this).parent(cardId).find(".pause").prop("disabled", false);
     });
  
  //On clicking pause, enable play and delete.
      $(cardId).find(".pause").on("click", function () {
         $(this).prop("disabled", true);
         $(this).parent(cardId).find(".delete").prop("disabled", false);
         $(this).parent(cardId).find(".play").prop("disabled", false);
     });
}
}
```